# ROC-AUC is high but PR-AUC value is very low

Tags: pytorch, precision-recall

I am working on DNA sequences data and using CNN in Pytorch. My dataset is hugely imbalanced.

positive class samples (~500)

negative class samples (~150,000)

So I am using WeightedRandomSampler to oversample and balance classes before feeding to data loader.

I use a 5-fold cross-validation. When I did few test runs, I could get a decent ROC value but the PR-AUC value seems to be really low.

For fold 1:

roc auc 0.9667848699763594

precision auc 0.055329116326074484

For fold 2:

roc auc 0.8476321207961566

precision auc 0.03307627288669479

For fold 3:

roc auc 0.9528898540612085

precision auc 0.05020178518546394

I suspect that there are lot of false negatives. Since the positive class samples (~500) is very low compared to negative class samples (~150,000) the model learns the negative class better and predicts most of the test samples as negative.

I tried weighing the positive class using

```
weight = [50.0]

class_weight = torch.FloatTensor(weight).to(device)

criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(pos_weight=class_weight)
```

By doing this, almost all samples are predicted as positive.

I tried Adaptive learning rates as well but the precision-recall values do not seem to improve.
**Can someone guide me and let me know the ideas to improve Precision and Recall values?**

Thanks!